# NEVERALLOW error when writing a SEPolicy rule

Tags: android-source, selinux

I am new to AOSP world, and definitely new to SELinux and SEPolicy.
I see in the logcat the following two errors are logged as soon as I faceunlock my device:

```
avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14402 scontext=u:r:hal_camera_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W libc    : Access denied finding property "ro.camera.req.fmq.size"
```

So if I add the following SEPolicy rule to `hal_camera_default.te` file, I get a `NEVERALLOW` error while building the ROM:

```
allow hal_camera_default default_prop:file read;
```

So I read that I have to be more specific when writing SEPolicy but I am not an expert in SELinux.

Can you please advise me which rules and what labels, and what `te` files that I need to add the new rules/labels while they don't trigger the NEVERALLOW error?

Appreciate your help in advance.